# Why does Process.setsid require root privileges in ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, daemon, root

In Ruby, a call to `Process.setsid` fails with "Operation not permitted" error if it's run as non-superuser. Try:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Process.setsid
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted
    from (irb):1:in `setsid'
    from (irb):1
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Or, it fails with the same error if I change the uid or the process using `Process.uid=` method. It works fine if I run the Ruby program as root, and I do not change the UID of the process during runtime.

However, in Ubuntu's or some other distro's shell, the `setsid` (reference: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid ) program does not require superuser privileges.

I understand that `stdsid` resets the program's session, which is also useful when daemonizing a process. In my code, I'm attempting to change the UID as well as daemonize it, while also resetting the session.

Hence, I'm curious why `Process.setsid` requires the said privileges, while the `setsid` program on most UNIX like OSes does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Process.setsid](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-setsid) is a thin wrap around POSIX [setsid(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) whose man page says:

> Errors
>
> EPERM
>
> The process group ID of any process equals the PID of the calling
>   process. Thus, in particular, setsid() fails if the calling process is
>   already a process group leader.

When your program runs, it's already a group leader. When deamonizing, you're expected to fork a new process for your daemon. `Process.setsid` works without EPERM error after you fork:

```
$ irb
irb> Process.setsid
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted
    from (irb):1:in `setsid'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/dbenhur/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb> fork { Process.setsid }
=> 3359
```

Take a look at [Rexec](https://github.com/ioquatix/rexec/blob/master/lib/rexec/daemon/controller.rb) or [unicorn](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb) for examples of POSIX daemonization in Ruby.

The setsid(1) program doesn't get an EPERM error because it forks before calling setsid(2). See [line 31 here](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=users/lamont/util-linux.git;a=blob;f=sys-utils/setsid.c;h=baf3b0aae4de642727b4c025aa9206bf10e699ad;hb=HEAD#l31)

Comment: The Linux Programming Interface book (which I highly recommend) describes the reasoning behind this restriction: process group leaders have a PGID that matches their own PID, and any child processes in the same process group have a PGID that matches the PID of the process group leader. If the process group leader were able to change its session ID, you'd still have those children with PGIDs pointing to the old process group leader's PID, even though it belongs to a new session, which breaks the requirement that processes in a process group must belong to the same session.